# Can't open port 25

Tags: linux, proxy, port, mail-server

I have a weird issue.
I am running a mail server behind a proxy. On the proxy all mail related ports are forwarded to the mail server:

```
    peter@proxy:~$ sudo iptables -S
    [sudo] password for peter: 
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens160 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.15/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.5/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see all the mailing related ports are forwarded to the mail server (10.10.0.5). I can telnet from outside into all the ports, except 25. From the proxy I can also telnet into the mail server on port 25. So the port is blocked on the proxy side.
Nothing else is listening on port 25:

```
    peter@proxy:~$ sudo netstat -plutn
    [sudo] password for peter: 
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1457/sshd       
    tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1512/apache2    
    tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1508/xinetd     
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1512/apache2    
    tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      1508/xinetd     
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1457/sshd
```

This is what I get when I try telneting from the outside:

```
    peter@ubuntu-desktop:~$ telnet mx0.xyz.com 25
    Trying 5.199.xxx.yyy...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

```
    peter@ubuntu-desktop:~$ telnet mx0.xyz.com 110
    Trying 5.199.xxx.yyy...
    Connected to mx0.xyz.com.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    +OK POP3 ready
    quit
    +OK
    Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Same for the other ports.
I can send emails but I cannot receive any, the gmail server reports a **Connection refused** error.

```
    [mx0.xyz.com. 5.199.xxx.yyy: FAILED_PRECONDITION: connect error (111): Connection refused]
```

How can I figure out what's blocking port 25 and how can I open it?

Comment: Use tcpdump on the external and internal interface on the proxy to see what's happening on port 25.